# MySQLdb load csv file using Python

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-python

I am trying to push large files to MySQL rds at Amazon. I have created simple python script for this. using MySQLdb connector.

```
import MySQLdb
sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{}'
INTO TABLE system_work
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;;"""

j=5
connection = MySQLdb.connect (host="mysql.cwzmkcey6nhb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",port=3306,user="myuser", passwd="myspass",db="mydb")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql.format('myfile_%s.csv' % j))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

But this script failed with error

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version')
```

Now I have found my Sql client option to counter this issue, we are required to pass following option of mysql client.

```
--local-infile=1
```

My Question is how can we pass this using python MySQLdb function, or there any other way to upload csv files to amazon cluster, I have 200 files to push.
connection.close()

Comment: you can't. it has to be given to the mysql server when it starts up. this is a security setting, and allowing clients to arbitrarily set it would kill any security it offered.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your information, If there any other way possible to push csv files Amazon rds mysql?